# Update field to null in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm using mongoengine. I want be able to set my field to null in database whenever eg. string is empty.

I tried the following, It seems to me whenever I pass None the field is skipped and I can't replace the existing value.
Is this even possible?

```py
if user.contact_phone_number == "":
    user.contact_phone_number = None
```

My document:

```py
contact_phone_number = StringField(
    db_field="contactPhoneNumber",
    regex=RE_CONTACT_PHONE,
    unique=False,
    sparse=True,
    required=False,
    null=True
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any problem to set a StringField to None, see below

```
from mongoengine import *

connect()

class TestDoc(Document):
    s = StringField()

TestDoc(s='test').save()

t = TestDoc.objects.first()
assert t.s == 'test'

t.s = ""
t.save()

t = TestDoc.objects.first()
assert t.s is ""

t.s = None
t.save()

t = TestDoc.objects.first()
assert t.s is None
```

Comment: I have found that setting to None doesn't sets value to null as I expected, it just removes the field, so you can assign again later.